# CMake calling another build system

Tags: cmake, clion

I need to work on a codebase that uses another build system, in this case Fastbuild.

I would like to work on it using CLion, which means I need a CMakeLists.txt.  It easy enough to import all the files I want to work on.

How can I set it up to call an external script when I want to build an executable?